# DrawMeshInstancedProcedural with Single Pass Instanced Rendering in Unity XR project

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens

I'm procedurally rendering a whole bunch of meshes using DrawMeshInstancedProcedural and a custom shader along the lines of https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html which works fine on PC. I'm now trying to use this in a Hololen2 project. If I'm following correctly, the more efficient XR rendering method of "Single Pass Instanced" is also making use of this GPU instance capability to draw the scene's geometry for each eye. Does this mean I can't do both or is there something I need to do to handle this combination correctly in the shader or DrawMeshInstancedProcedural code (ie. per-eye instance vs per DrawMeshInstancedProcedural instance)?

With "Multi-pass" set my scene renders correctly but with "Single Pass Instanced" the transforms are off for my instances in one eye (ie. Seems the instance ID based lookup of the per-instance transforms is off).

I think the issue is the conflict between the instance ID in the vertex shader being for the instanced meshes call vs the stereo render.

I did wonder if the statement at the bottom of the [Unity Hololens Stereo render docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRenderingHoloLens.html) is a clue – “Graphics.DrawProceduralIndirect() and CommandBuffer.DrawProceduralIndirect() get all of their arguments from a compute buffer, so we can’t easily increase the instance count. Therefore you will have to manually double the instance count contained in your compute buffers.”

Any help or suggestions would be great.

```
private struct MeshProperties
{
    public Matrix4x4 mat;
    public Color color; 

    public static int Size()
    {
        //Size for buffer
        return
            sizeof(float) * 4 * 4 + // matrix;
            sizeof(float) * 4;      // colour;
    }
}
...
MeshProperties[] meshProperties = new MeshProperties[vertCount];
for (int i = 0; i < vertCount; i++)
{     
    MeshProperties meshProps = new MeshProperties();
    // populate transform and color of each point (instance)
    meshProperties[i] = meshProps;
}
ComputeBuffer computeBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(vertCount, MeshProperties.Size());
computeBuffer.SetData(meshProperties);
material.SetBuffer("_Properties", computeBuffer);
...
Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedProcedural(
    instanceMesh, // the mesh to draw at each location
    0,
    material,
    bounds,
    vertexCount);
```

```
Shader "RBGA Glyphs"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Ambient("Ambient", Color) = (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            Tags {"LightMode"="ForwardBase"}
            
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct VertInput
            {
                float4 pos : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
            };

            struct VertOutput
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                half4 color : COLOR;
                
                UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
            };

            half4 _Ambient;
            float4x4 _WorldTrans;

            struct MeshProperties 
            {
                float4x4 mat; //matrix
                float4 color; //vertex colour
            };
            StructuredBuffer<MeshProperties> _Properties;

            VertOutput vert(VertInput vin, uint instanceID: SV_InstanceID)
            {
                VertOutput vout;
                UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(vin);
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(VertOutput, vout); 
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(vout);
                
                float3 norm = mul(_Properties[instanceID].mat, vin.normal);
                norm = mul(_WorldTrans, norm);
                float3 worldNormal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(norm);

                // dot product between normal and light direction for standard diffuse (Lambert) lighting
                half nl = saturate(dot(worldNormal, normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz)));

                // add ambient
                nl = clamp(nl + _Ambient, 0, 1);
                
                float4 pos = mul(_Properties[instanceID].mat, vin.pos);
                pos = mul(_WorldTrans, pos);
                vout.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(pos);
                vout.color = _Properties[instanceID].color * nl;
                return vout;
            }
            
            half4 frag(VertOutput vin) : SV_Target
            {
                return vin.color;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging into what UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID (https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/CGIncludes/UnityInstancing.cginc) was doing and much painful experimentation, it turns out I was correct that the note in the docs “Therefore you will have to manually double the instance count contained in your compute buffers.” was indeed a clue (aka the answer).
In the case of stereo instance rendering, the per-instance buffers need to be twice as long and duplicated (interlaced) to render for each eye (for each instance of the geometry being rendered). The unity_StereoEyeIndex is calculated as inputInstanceID & 0x01 so you need

```
Computebuffer[0] // matrix for instance 0 left eye
Computebuffer[1] // matrix for instance 0 right eye (ie. Duplicate of Computebuffer[0])
Computebuffer[2] // matrix for instance 1 left eye
Computebuffer[3] // matrix for instance 1 right eye (ie. Duplicate of Computebuffer[2])
…
Computebuffer[instanceCount *2]
```

The call to DrawMeshInstancedProcedural or the count buffer argument to DrawMeshInstancedIndirect should also use a count 2 * the number of instances you’re rendering in the scene.

Comment: Why do you have to double the compute buffer? Would this work: 1) leave the computer buffer as is, not interleaved 2) in Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedProcedural pass vertexCount * 2, 3) in the shader, do _Properties[instanceId / 2].

Comment: So I'm trying to do the same thing with Shader Graph. Did this improve your performance noticeably?

Answer (score 0):

If your non built-in shader isn't written for instancing. After enabling Single Pass Instanced Rendering, some GameObjects may only render in one eye. This is because the associated custom shaders do not have the appropriate properties for instancing. See [Single Pass Stereo Rendering for HoloLens from Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRenderingHoloLens.html) for how to address this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I think all these shader macros are added correctly as they’re the same ones needed for the GPU instance rendering of meshes with DrawMeshInstancedProcedural (I’ll update the question above with example code).

Comment: Wonder the version number of Unity and more detail about which XR pipeline (legacy XR pipeline or XR SDK or OpenXR)  are you using.

Comment: This current example is still using legacy XR pipeline on latest Unity 2019 LTS as it also uses WLT (which I'm not sure supports OpenXR). Could try a new 2020 or 2021 project with XRSDK or OpenXR to see if this is an issue in the older pipeline vs just a limitation or adjustment to the instancing code I'm missing.

Comment: Microsoft’s current recommended Unity configuration for HoloLens 2 is Unity 2020.3 LTS with the latest Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin, please have a try with 2020.3 LTS and see the behavior. Ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version

Comment: Same results after setting up a new project with 2020.3.30f1 using OpenXR plugin. Maybe I'm going to need to put together a simplified sample project of using DrawMeshInstancedProcedural with Single Pass rendering for Hololens2 and see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue with a clean 2020.3.30f1 OpenXR project using the example code from the Unity docs. Left eye correctly renders the instances, right eye only renders regular models in the scene (no instances). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect.html